# Wish parameter in sns.boxplot is not reflected on the graphic when it changes

Tags: boxplot

Assume we have a simple dataset and I want to determine the upper and the lower boundaries `q1=27` and `q3=51`.

As you expected the boundaries should be `-9` and `87`. But when I use `sns.boxplot` it gives me shorter whiskers. More interesting thing is that, when I change the `whis` with any values chart does not give a reaction. As follows:

```
sns.boxplot(y=df[variable],whis=2)
plt.title('Boxplot')
plt.show()
```